# Mirror Production Mongo Data for Analytics

Tags: mongodb, analytics

I have a Mongo cluster that backs an application that I use in production. It's very important to my business and clustered across a number of boxes to optimize for speed and redundancy. I'd like to make the data in said cluster available for running analytical queries and enqueued tasks, but I definitely don't want these to harm production performance. Is it possible to just mirror all of my data against a single box I throw into the cluster with some special tag that I can then use for analytics? It's fine if it's slow. I just want it to be cheap and not to affect production read/write speeds.

Comment: is your production mongod part of a replica set?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about redundancy, I assume you have a replica set.

In that case you can use a [hidden replica set member](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/#replica-set-hidden-members) to perform the calculations you need.

Just keep in mind that the member count must be odd. If you add a node you might need to also add an arbiter. Or maybe you can just hide one of the already existing members.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to increase querying speed having a lot of data, you have to look might look [into sharding with mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/). Basically what it does is dividing your big amount of data into small shards and stores them on different machines.

If you are looking to increase redundancy (in order to make backup or to be able to do offline processing without touching primary servers) you have to look into [replication with mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/). If you are doing replication, keep in mind that the data on the replicas will be always lagging behind a primary (nothing to worry about, but just need to know this fact to decide can you allow read from the replicas). As it was pointed by Rafa, [hidden replica sets](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/#replica-set-hidden-members) are well suited for backup and offline data processing. They will still be able to get all the data from primary (with small lag), but are invisible to secondary reads and can not become primary.

There is a nice [mongodb course](https://education.mongodb.com/courses/10gen/M102/) which is talking in depth about replication and sharding, so may be it is worth listening and trying it.

Comment: that's not at all relevant to the question asked - he doesn't want to handle more data, he wants to handle an additional query pattern on existing data.